# Which Xamarin.Android apk file should I give to beta testers

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, apk, beta

Hello all and thanks in advance!  I'm working on a Xamarin app and am at the point where I want to get it to a few trusted beta testers with Android devices.  I used Visual Studio to generate an APK file and was able to do a cold install on my Android 10 Samsung phone.  However, VS generated all of the APK files shown in the attached photo.  On a hunch I installed the last one (com.companyname.tepcochordscalefinder-Signed.apk) and it worked fine.  However, I feel I need to further inform myself so as not to screw up when I give it to the beta testers so I have 2 questions.

1.) I didn't sign anything so what is the significance or meaning of the signed vs. unsigned apk files?
2.) How do I know which version to give to which user? I'm assuming Google Play will take care of that for in store purchases but I want a few weeks of beta testing before I upload an app bundle and want to get the right versions to the testers.

Again, thanks in advance for all relevant info! [VS generated apk files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTw74.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: those are different architectures - which one you give to testers will depend on what architecture their device supports.

Comment: I would suggest to either use something like AppCenter or Play Store Alpha channel to distribute your APK and invite your testers in those systems, rather than distributing APK files manually.